# dojo store/memory query - not equal

Tags: javascript, dojo

To get retrieve results for when `name` matches whatever is in `fieldName` I do -

```
Memory.query({
   name: fieldName
})
```

How can I find all results that `name` does not match whats in `fieldName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `dojo/store/Memory#query` a function:

```
store.query(function (item) {
    return item.name !== fieldName;
});
```